# Unable to delete from SQLite DB in Xamarin app

Tags: c#, linq, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a class Product to store some info about a product and want to save this into a SQLite DB in my Xamarin application.

```
class Product
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement, Column("ID")]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }


    public Product(string name, string category)
    {
        Name = name;
        Category = category;
    }

    public Product()
    {

    }
}
```

In my code I create a Product object as

```
Product s = new Product();
        s.Name = some_name;
        s.Category = some_category;
```

and insert in my DB by:

```
var db = new SQLiteConnection(db_path);
var table = db.Table<Product>();
db.Insert(s);
```

The problem is that the primary key is always 0 apparently and when I try to delete a record in my table by passing an item I have a null

```
private void deleteThisProduct(Product item)
{
    var db = new SQLiteConnection(db_path);
    var table = db.Table<Product>();
    var toDelete = table.Where(x => x.ID == item.ID).FirstOrDefault();
    if (toDelete != null)
        {
            db.Delete(toDelete);
            Toast.MakeText(this, "Delete Successfully", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this, "Not Found", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }
}
```

Whatever item I pass to the delete function, toDelete is always null and I cannote delete the record from DB. 
Weirdly, if all my records (of class Product) have a primary key of 0, my Linq query should find something, but it is always returning a null.

What am I doing wrong? Is my Product class the issue? Thanks.

Just to be clear, even if on the code above I simply do:

```
db.Delete(item)
```

I cannot remove the associated record from the table.

Comment: The Product Id cannot be 0 in the table as this field is marked as PrimaryKey. Create a method to get all items and so you can verify what is the Id they have. Method `deleteThisProduct()` you could only pass in the productId `private void deleteThisProduct(int productId)` as this is all you are using.

Comment: That is why I find all this weird. The ID is not set properly and this creates problems when calling db.Delete()

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to Save your Product class in a Product.cs:`

```
[Serializable()]
    public class Product
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }`
}
```

and in the create table:

"CREATE TABLE Product(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,.....

Comment: Product is already in a Product.cs. The only thing I didn't do is adding [Serializable()] at the beginning

Comment: have you declared the db field as primary key in the table definition?

Comment: Yes. This is done automatically when I pass my Product class to db.CreateTable<Product>()

Comment: did you open the db file in sqlite editor and looked at what is the schema of your product table. there should be ID integer not null prlmary key autoincrement.

Comment: I don't know how to do that cause when the DB is created it gets stored in a hidden location. I guess this is always the case with mobile apps.

Comment: try to store it in an externalstoragedirectory (at least for testing). Then you can copy it from there to your workdesk and analyze it with DB Browser for SQlite (which is free). string testFilePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.ToString(), "MyTestPath"), "MyTest.db3");

Comment: Don't forget to give write external storage permission!